# Selenium C# WebDriver +data driven while loop

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

Unable to generate a loop that every `userid` finishes the test passing to the next `userid` via the Excel.

```
        PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sales Panel")).Click();
        ExcelLib.PopulateInCollection(@"C:\Users\Numg\Desktop\da\Copy_of_webusers.xlsx");
        PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("web_user_user_id")).SendKeys(ExcelLib.ReadData(2, "Id"));             
        PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Ok")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("4")).Click();
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    var option = PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("aggrupations_653_shares"));
    var SelectElement = new SelectElement(option);
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    SelectElement.SelectByValue("3");
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#bet-group > #send > i.fa.fa-arrow-right")).Click();
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("code")).SendKeys("testQA");
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#new_reduction > input[name=\"commit\"]")).Click();
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Clear")).Click();
}
```

---

This is the class for Excel

```
class ExcelLib
{

       private static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string fileName)
   {
       //open file and returns as Stream
       FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
       //Createopenxmlreader via ExcelReaderFactory
       IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream); //.xlsx
       //Set the First Row as Column Name
       excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
       //Return as DataSet
       DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
       //Get all the Tables
       DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
       //Store it in DataTable
       DataTable resultTable = table["Sheet1"];

       //return
       return resultTable;
   }

 static List<Datacollection> dataCol = new List<Datacollection>();

   public static void PopulateInCollection(string fileName)
   {
       DataTable table = ExcelToDataTable(fileName);

       //Iterate through the rows and columns of the Table
       for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
       {
           for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
           {
               Datacollection dtTable = new Datacollection()
               {
                   rowNumber = row,
                   colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
                   colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()      
               };
               //Add all the details for each row
               dataCol.Add(dtTable);
           }
       }
   }

   public static string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
   {
       try
       {
           //Retriving Data using LINQ to reduce much of iterations
           string data = (from colData in dataCol
                          where colData.colName == columnName && colData.rowNumber == rowNumber
                          select colData.colValue).SingleOrDefault();

           //var datas = dataCol.Where(x => x.colName == columnName && x.rowNumber == rowNumber).SingleOrDefault().colValue;
           return data.ToString();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           return null;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't using a framework (like TestNG, Microsoft unit tests, JUnit, etc.) that supports defining a data source as a class annotation.

If you were, this would be easy - you'd have something like `data-source.currentRow["columnName"].value()` and the framework would automatically handle your assertions and moving from row to row.

With the setup you're using you'd use a foreach structure to access each record in your list:

```
foreach Datacollection rowdata in dataCol do
{
    string userid = rowdata.colValue;
    // everything you intend to do with that userid
    // Your test assertions
}
```

This is pretty basic C# programming - `foreach` will iterate through your static list automatically, but will register to any test harness as *one test*.

Comment: What exactly should I use, and where I'm changing it exactly in the code I'll explain